# Why is my condition showing false results?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have this condition using JavaScript, I have 2 text boxes where I'll compare the input ( inputs are numbers). The condition is when textbox 2 is less than textbox 1 it will have an alert message that says textbox2 must be greater than textbox2. So when the input is like this

```
textbox2  > textbox1

15  > 1  = alert pops out
15  > 2  = not ok
15  > 3  = not ok
15  > 4  = not ok
15  > 5  = not ok
15  > 6  = not ok
15  > 7  = not ok
15  > 8  = not ok
15  > 9  = not ok
15  > 10  =  ok
onwards is ok.
```

Why is it that when it compares 2 to 9 it doesn't alert anything?

Here is my condition:

```
if(textbox2.value < textbox2.value)
{
    document.getElementById("lblStatus1").innerHTML = 'Pay1 must be greater than To1';
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle about this? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Because an `<input>`'s `value` is always a `String` and the `"1"` of the `"15"` is `< "9"`. [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: You're comparing the same values "if(textbox2.value < textbox2.value)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings. Which will not work as you intended to.

Use `parseInt()`:

```
if(parseInt(textbox2.value) < parseInt(textbox2.value))
{
    document.getElementById("lblStatus1").innerHTML = 'Pay1 must be greater than To1';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are comparing strings, which is different than comparing numerical values.

"15" is < "2" Because it's evaluated alphabetically character by character . The leading '1' in '15' causes '15' to be < '2'

Comment: How would that affect "2" and "9"?

Comment: where do you see 2 compared to 9?

Comment: In the original post he says "why is it when it compares 2 to 9 it doesn't alert anythings".

Comment: OP mentions "2 to 9", which is what TGH is saying would happen (due to alphabetical evaluation)

Comment: If that is his case... "2" still would be less than "9".  I think it's cause he is comparing the same values in textbox2.value and textbox2.value.  He probably copy and pasted his code.

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. - go to jsfiddle or the dev tool bar and type in 
if ('2' < '9')
    alert('hello');
You'll see that hello is printed even though they are "strings".

Comment: It's to be expected that '2' < '9'. But '15' is < '2' because of the leading '1'

Comment: @VtoCorleone, yes, but we're not comparing that. We're comparing '15' to values '2' through '9', which is the issue.

Comment: I agree with you guys about the string issue.  But the OP used 2 and 9 as his examples.  I was assuming with the question and his code example, he pasted his code which is comparing the same values.  Either way, looks like you guys were right.  I'll +1 ya both.

Answer (score 1):

Are you parsing your input values? If not, you're doing a comparison against strings which would result in an issue. Something like this:

`parseInt(inputVal1, 10) > parseInt(inputVal2, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

If you copy and pasted your code...

You're comparing the same values textbox2.value and textbox2.value.

Answer (score 0):

You are having an issue related to validating strings. Try to parse the values as numbers:

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YubU7/)

#### HTML

```
Value 1<input type="text" id="text1" /><br />
Value 2<input type="text" id="text2" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Validate" onclick="doValidate();" />
```

#### Js

```
function doValidate() {
    var value1 = new Number(document.getElementById("text1").value);
    var value2 = new Number(document.getElementById("text2").value);
    
    if (value2 < value1)
        alert("Value 2 must be higher than Value 1!");
}
```

Notice the usage of **new Number()** in JavaScript. This effectivelly turns the string into a number (if it is a valid number).